# Variable '$_data' cannot be non input type in GraphQL mutation with Prisma

Tags: graphql, mutation, prisma

I am using Prisma with GraphQL and get errors when I run the mutatioin.
I deployed prisma succussfully and binded it with local graphQL.

-- datamodel.graphql - prisma setting

```
type Link {
  id: ID! @unique
  description: String!
  url: String!
  postedBy: User
}

type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  links: [Link!]!
}
```

-- schema.graphql - local setting

```
# import Link from "./generated/prisma.graphql"
type Query {
  info: String!
  feed: [Link!]!
}

type Mutation {
  post(url: String!, description: String!): Link!
  signup(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!): AuthPayload
  login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
}

type AuthPayload {
  token: String
  user: User
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
  links: [Link!]!
}
```

Resolver for signup mutation is

```
async function signup(parent, args, context, info) {
  // 1
  const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10)
  // 2
  const user = await context.db.mutation.createUser({
    data: { ...args, password },
  }, `{ id }`)

  // 3
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, APP_SECRET)

  // 4
  return {
    token,
    user,
  }
}
```

And this is .graphqlconfig.yml content

```
projects:
  app:
    schemaPath: src/schema.graphql
    extensions:
      endpoints:
        default: http://localhost:4000
  database:
    schemaPath: src/generated/prisma.graphql
    extensions:
      prisma: database/prisma.yml
```

GraphQL query I run is .

```
mutation {
  signup(
    name: "Alice"
    email: "alice@graph.cool"
    password: "graphql"
  ) {
    token
    user {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

And the response I got when I run this is

```
{
  "data": {
    "signup": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable '$_data' cannot be non input type 'UserCreateInput!'. (line 1, column 19):\nmutation ($_data: UserCreateInput!) {\n                  ^",
      "locations": [],
      "path": [
        "createUser"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can'find the reason of this.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever found out what was causing this? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: I am also running into the same issue, but can't seem to figure the cause of the issue

Answer (score 4):

Try use prisma deploy --force

This worked for me.

Comment: This fixed my problem!

Comment: If you're just following tutorial, you might miss the warning when you run "prisma deploy" in the Authorisation chapter. Try again with the --force flag to ensure the new columns get deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by changing to the right endpoint in index.js

```
const server = new GraphQLServer({
   typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
   resolvers,
   context: req => ({
       ...req,
       db: new Prisma({
           typeDefs: 'src/generated/prisma.graphql',
           endpoint: 'http://localhost:4466/local/dev',
           secret: 'secret',
           debug: true,
       }),
   }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your prisma.yml was wrong.

```
# The endpoint represents the HTTP endpoint for your Prisma API. It encodes
# several pieces of information:
# * Prisma server (`localhost:4466` in this example)
# * Service name (`myservice` in this example)
# * Stage (`dev` in this example)
# NOTE: When service name and stage are set to `default`, they can be omitted.
# Meaning http://myserver.com/default/default can be written as http://myserver.com.
endpoint: http://localhost:4466/myservice/dev
```